# Passing parameters to a Page using constructors

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

In my application I have two pages placed on a Navigation Window.

**Page 1** the Main Page and has three buttons on top ( like a ribbon menu) and a Frame ( on second half of the page to navigate within frame)

**Page 2** - is the second page that will be directed within the frame when the buttons in Page 1 is clicked.

In Page 2 I have a `Datagrid` displaying list of servers for test environment -  TestServer1 .. TestServerN, for development -DevServer1...DevServern and for Production -PrdServer1..PrdServerN.

currently when these button's are cliked , all the servers get displayed in the datagrid, but my concern is to display in the following order,

when user clicks

**tstbutton** ( test) - it should navigate to page 2 and display only servers which belongs to test system.

**devbutton** ( dev)-  it should navigate to page 2 and display only servers which belongs to development system.

**prdbutton** (prd) - it should navigate to page 2 and display only servers which belongs to production system.

I have tried the following, but I could achieve only for one server, by passing paramter through constructor.

**Page1.cs**

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
public Page1()
{
 InitializeComponent();
}

private void PRD_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
//  Server x = new Server();
Page2 pg = new Page2();
this.NavigationService.Navigate(pg);
}

private void TST_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
// this works, only if I pass one paramaterized constructor
Server s = new Server();
Page2 pg = new Page2(s);
this.NavigationService.Navigate(pg);
}

private void DEV_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
//  Server y = new Server();
Page2 pg = new Page2();
this.NavigationService.Navigate(pg);
}
}
```

**Page2.cs**

```
public partial class Page2: Page
{       
public Page2()
{
InitializeComponent();
}   
public Page2(Server s)
{
Db_Entities db = new Db_Entities();
string tst = "TEST";
var query1 = (from a in this.db.Servers
             where a.ServerID.Contains(tst)
             orderby a.ServerID
             select a).ToList();
datagrid1.ItemsSource = query1.ToList();
} 
}
```

The above code works fine.. but if I uncomment the code for the other two click event's for the prdtst and devtst button, and I pass tha parameters along with (Server s) .. there is ambiguity and errors.. how to achieve for the other two servers ? any ideas ??

**EDIT**

I have following are the errors when I add these extra blocks to my code

```
public Page2(Server x)
{
Db_Entities db = new Db_Entities();
string prd = "PRD";
var query1 = (from a in this.db.Servers
             where a.ServerID.Contains(prd)
             orderby a.ServerID
             select a).ToList();
datagrid1.ItemsSource = query1.ToList();
} 
public Page2(Server x)
{
Db_Entities db = new Db_Entities();
string dev = "DEV";
var query1 = (from a in this.db.Servers
             where a.ServerID.Contains(dev)
             orderby a.ServerID
             select a).ToList();
datagrid1.ItemsSource = query1.ToList();
}
```

**Error 1** - I get this error 2 times
Type 'FN_UI.Views.Page2' already defines a member called 'Page2' with the same parameter types

**Error 2** - I get this error 3 times
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'FN_UI.Views.Page2.Page2(FN_UI.Server)' and 'FN_UI.Views.Page2.Page2(FN_UI.Server)'

link for the complete code - https://gist.github.com/userXemY/c477c25c0c1641470c35

Comment: Can You explain in detail please ?

(By the way, ambiguous method overrides usually are a concern for the compiler, be sure to have them avoided ).

And, the keyword class is missing for page2

Comment: ok I will paste my entire code.. so that you can have an idea..

Comment: I have added code to my question, for complete reference, kindly check this link - https://gist.github.com/userXemY/c477c25c0c1641470c35

Comment: Like i said.

You have three constructors with the same signature.

That is not good.

You must redisign them. No compiler will accept this ( afaik i know ).

Comment: yes you sound right.. but how to pass the parameters ?

Comment: You can wrap Your servers into own classes, if You like.

Or, You can add another parameter to the constructor and differentiate by that inside the constructor, let it be called servertype, or what ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have three constructors with the same parameter type(s) in one class.

And do you actually use the `Server s` constructor parameter anywhere?

Anyway, write only one constructor by adding the search string as another parameter:

```
public Page2(Server s, string what)
{
    InitializeComponent(); // and don't forget this

    Db_Entities db = new Db_Entities();
    var query1 = (from a in this.db.Servers
                  where a.ServerID.Contains(what)
                  orderby a.ServerID
                  select a).ToList();
    datagrid1.ItemsSource = query1.ToList();

    // where is s used?
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
Server s = new Server();
Page2 pg = new Page2(s, "TEST");
```

and

```
Server s = new Server();
Page2 pg = new Page2(s, "PRN");
```

and

```
Server s = new Server();
Page2 pg = new Page2(s, "DEV");
```

Comment: the query is different for each system ( tst/prd and dev) .. do i have to place three different querys then ?

Comment: Sorry, "s" is not used anywhere .. my mistake

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihren Vorschlag :-)